# Mutexes in c++ using wxwidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, mutex

I was reading the following example at for the mutex protection :-

visit http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxmutex.html#wxmutex

There is a commented code here as :-

```
 //we store some numbers in this global array which is presumably used by
 //several threads simultaneously
```

Does running several threads means running different copies of the same thread(if it is this , then please help me doing this ) or functions those have different functionality but access to the critical section.

Comment: what do u mean by : "running different copies of the same thread".  It doesn't seem to make sense to me...

Comment: Suppose car is a class and there are several cars trying to enter a narrow lane so for example MyThread is a class so there could be multiple threads

Comment: I'm guessing by "same thread" you meant same class type (derived from wxThread), because in wxWidgets, you create a thread class by inheriting from wxThread. Each object of this class type will start a separate thread. Or if you have different classes inheriting from wxThread, then each object of any of these types will start new threads.

Answer (score 0):

The example assumes you will spawn multiple instances of t he thread MyThread which will mutate the variable:

```
wxArrayInt s_data;
```

since multiple threads access the same data you need to handle the synchronisation, with for example a mutex in this example.

```
s_mutexProtectingTheGlobalList->Lock();

s_data.Add(num);

s_mutexProtectingTheGlobalList->Unlock();
```

This way, only 1 thread will be able to access the data at the same time, and you prevent multithreading issues.

If you dont do this, there is a chance threads might use outdated data when interrupting eachother, here is a basic example:

```
int a = 0;

void foo()
{
int b = a;
 b += 1;
 a = b;
}
```

if there are 2 threads using this function on the same data, the following might occur:

```
thread 1:
   reads a into b  (a = 0, b = 0)
   adds 1 to local b (a = 0, b = 1)
   end of timeslice, switches to thread 2
thread 2:
   reads a into b (a = 0, b = 0)
   adds 1 to local b (a = 0, b = 1)
   writes b back into a (a = 1, b = 1)
   end of timeslice/operation
thread 1:
   writes b back into a (a = 1, b = 1)
```

so because 2 threads have a copy of the data, which in case of  thread 2 is out-dated, 
they will overwrite eachother, so instead of a being 2, it is 1
thread 1